# Complex but not Symplectic

Tags: complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

For every  even integer  $n>2$, does  there exist a smooth $n$  dimensional  manifold $M$  that admits a complex structure but not a symplectic one?

Comment: Well, for $n>2$, yes.  For example, when $n>2$ is even, $S^1\times S^{n-1}$ has a complex structure (the Calabi-Eckmann complex structure), but it cannot have a symplectic structure because it has vanishing second deRham cohomology.

Comment: Then the Gromov result of Open manifolds can not be generalized in general? But on the other hand, Yau's conjecture that every almost complex manifold admits a complex structure. In particular if it is true, symplectic manifolds are a subset of complex ones and these Calabi-Eckmann manifolds asserts that are not equal is it true?

Comment: Gromov's convex integration methods and h-principle methods in these cases depend on the manifold not having any compact component, so, no his results for open manifolds do not carry over to the compact case.  It is not known whether a compact almost-complex (in particular, a symplectic) manifold of dimension at least 6 always has a complex structure; this is an open problem.   Dimension 4 is, of course, different.